# Graph representation with a value in each vertex

Tags: algorithm, graph

I know how to represent a graph with an adjacency list representation and I also know the matrix representation (Reference: Algorithms Design Manual)

The adjacency list representation is simply:

```
struct edge {
    int y;
    int weight;
    struct edge *next;
};

struct graph {
    int n;
    struct edge *edges[N];
}
```

But now I want to put the values in the vertex while the edges have no values

```
struct vertex {
    int value; // to be used for sums later
    struct vertex *parent;
    struct vertex *child;
}

struct edge {
    struct vertex *start;
    struct vertex *end;
}

struct graph {
    int n;
    struct vertex *v[N]; // array of vertices
    // How do I link the vertices and the edges?
    // struct edge
}
```

My question is how do I link the vertices with the edges?

Comment: Your data structure already links vertices with edges. What's your problem exactly?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish and what data do you have?  If you were to flesh out all the vertices, you could simply iterate through them and create an edge for every`v[i].parent` and `v[i].child` where both are non-null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct graph {
  int n_nodes;
  struct node {
    int value;
    int n_adjacents;
    int *adjacent_indices;
  } **nodes;
} graph;
```